# css overwrite parent style

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a website with a sidebar, I want certain elements to have a background color of yellow if they have the `currentPage` class. It works with my 'Home' tab, but I am trying to do the same with one of my nested tabs, in this case 'tagger.site' from 'Projects', I have the same class element added but it wont change the background color to yellow, even if i add the !important string. Is there some way to force my background color to change? Or do i need to change my css selector for currentPage

https://jsfiddle.net/martinradio/a0k2c5rv/12/

```css
/*
    DEMO STYLE
*/

@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,500,600,700";
body {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    background: #fafafa;
}

p {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 1.7em;
    color: #999;
}

.btn-info {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #b81717;
    border-color: #52b817;
}

a,
a:hover,
a:focus {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

.navbar {
    padding: 15px 10px;
    background: #fff;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.navbar-btn {
    box-shadow: none;
    outline: none !important;
    border: none;
}

.line {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #ddd;
    margin: 40px 0;
}

/* ---------------------------------------------------
    SIDEBAR STYLE
----------------------------------------------------- */

.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    align-items: stretch;
}

#sidebar {
    min-width: 250px;
    max-width: 250px;
    background: #EAE7DC; /* NAVBAR BACKGROUND */
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

#sidebar.active {
    margin-left: -250px;
}

#sidebar .sidebar-header {
    padding: 20px;
    /* background: #6d7fcc; */
}

#sidebar ul.components {
    /* padding: 20px 0; */
    /* border-bottom: 1px solid #47748b; */
}

#sidebar ul p {
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
}

#sidebar ul li a {
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    display: block;
}

.currentPage{
    background: #ffbd00 !important;
}


#sidebar ul li a:hover {
    color: #000;
    background: #D7D1BC; /* hover tab color */
}

#sidebar ul li.active>a,
a[aria-expanded="true"] {
    /* color: #fff; */
    background: #d1cbba; /* active tab */
}

a[data-toggle="collapse"] {
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown-toggle::after {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 20px;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

ul ul a {
    font-size: 0.9em !important;
    padding-left: 30px !important;
    background: #e4dece;    /* tab list color */
}

ul.CTAs {
    padding: 20px;
}

ul.CTAs a {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0.9em !important;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

/* ---------------------------------------------------
    CONTENT STYLE
----------------------------------------------------- */

#content {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    min-height: 100vh;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

/* ---------------------------------------------------
    MEDIAQUERIES
----------------------------------------------------- */

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    #sidebar {
        margin-left: -250px;
    }
    #sidebar.active {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
    #sidebarCollapse span {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

    <title>mr.me</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS CDN -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Our Custom CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    <!-- Font Awesome JS -->
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/solid.js" integrity="sha384-tzzSw1/Vo+0N5UhStP3bvwWPq+uvzCMfrN1fEFe+xBmv1C/AtVX5K0uZtmcHitFZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/fontawesome.js" integrity="sha384-6OIrr52G08NpOFSZdxxz1xdNSndlD4vdcf/q2myIUVO0VsqaGHJsB0RaBE01VTOY" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="wrapper" class="toggled">
        <!-- Sidebar  -->
        <nav id="sidebar">
            <div class="sidebar-header">
                <h3>Mrr</h3>
            </div>

            <ul class="list-unstyled components">
                <li class="currentPage" >
                    <a href="#" >Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#projectsSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Projects</a>
                    <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="projectsSubmenu">
                        <li class='currentPage'>
                            <a href="#">tagger.site</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">discogstagger.site</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">popularify.biz</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">more projects</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#contactSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Contact</a>
                    <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="contactSubmenu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Email</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Github</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">LinkedIn</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Resume</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#blogSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Blog</a>
                    <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="blogSubmenu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Post 1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Post 3</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Post 4</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Post 5</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>

        </nav>

        <!-- Page Content  -->
        <div id="content">

            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
                <div class="container-fluid">

                    <button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" class="btn btn-info">
                        <i class="fas fa-align-left"></i>
                        <span>Toggle Sidebar</span>
                                           </button>
                    
                </div>
            </nav>

            <h2>Collapsible Sidebar Using Bootstrap 4</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

            <div class="line"></div>

            <h2>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

            <div class="line"></div>

            <h2>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

            <div class="line"></div>

            <h3>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- jQuery CDN - Slim version (=without AJAX) -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- Popper.JS -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#sidebarCollapse').on('click', function () {
                $('#sidebar').toggleClass('active');
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your CSS selector from `.currentPage` to `.currentPage, .currentPage *` to also select all descendants of elements with the currentPage class.

```css
/*
    DEMO STYLE
*/

@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,500,600,700";
body {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    background: #fafafa;
}

p {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 1.7em;
    color: #999;
}

.btn-info {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #b81717;
    border-color: #52b817;
}

a,
a:hover,
a:focus {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

.navbar {
    padding: 15px 10px;
    background: #fff;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.navbar-btn {
    box-shadow: none;
    outline: none !important;
    border: none;
}

.line {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #ddd;
    margin: 40px 0;
}

/* ---------------------------------------------------
    SIDEBAR STYLE
----------------------------------------------------- */

.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    align-items: stretch;
}

#sidebar {
    min-width: 250px;
    max-width: 250px;
    background: #EAE7DC; /* NAVBAR BACKGROUND */
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

#sidebar.active {
    margin-left: -250px;
}

#sidebar .sidebar-header {
    padding: 20px;
    /* background: #6d7fcc; */
}

#sidebar ul.components {
    /* padding: 20px 0; */
    /* border-bottom: 1px solid #47748b; */
}

#sidebar ul p {
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
}

#sidebar ul li a {
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    display: block;
}

.currentPage, .currentPage *{
    background: #ffbd00 !important;
}


#sidebar ul li a:hover {
    color: #000;
    background: #D7D1BC; /* hover tab color */
}

#sidebar ul li.active>a,
a[aria-expanded="true"] {
    /* color: #fff; */
    background: #d1cbba; /* active tab */
}

a[data-toggle="collapse"] {
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown-toggle::after {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 20px;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

ul ul a {
    font-size: 0.9em !important;
    padding-left: 30px !important;
    background: #e4dece;    /* tab list color */
}

ul.CTAs {
    padding: 20px;
}

ul.CTAs a {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0.9em !important;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

/* ---------------------------------------------------
    CONTENT STYLE
----------------------------------------------------- */

#content {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    min-height: 100vh;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

/* ---------------------------------------------------
    MEDIAQUERIES
----------------------------------------------------- */

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    #sidebar {
        margin-left: -250px;
    }
    #sidebar.active {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
    #sidebarCollapse span {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

    <title>mr.me</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS CDN -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Our Custom CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    <!-- Font Awesome JS -->
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/solid.js" integrity="sha384-tzzSw1/Vo+0N5UhStP3bvwWPq+uvzCMfrN1fEFe+xBmv1C/AtVX5K0uZtmcHitFZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/fontawesome.js" integrity="sha384-6OIrr52G08NpOFSZdxxz1xdNSndlD4vdcf/q2myIUVO0VsqaGHJsB0RaBE01VTOY" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="wrapper" class="toggled">
        <!-- Sidebar  -->
        <nav id="sidebar">
            <div class="sidebar-header">
                <h3>Mrr</h3>
            </div>

            <ul class="list-unstyled components">
                <li class="currentPage" >
                    <a href="#" >Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#projectsSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Projects</a>
                    <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="projectsSubmenu">
                        <li class='currentPage'>
                            <a href="#">tagger.site</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">discogstagger.site</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">popularify.biz</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">more projects</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#contactSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Contact</a>
                    <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="contactSubmenu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Email</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Github</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">LinkedIn</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Resume</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#blogSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Blog</a>
                    <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="blogSubmenu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Post 1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Post 3</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Post 4</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Post 5</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>

        </nav>

        <!-- Page Content  -->
        <div id="content">

            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
                <div class="container-fluid">

                    <button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" class="btn btn-info">
                        <i class="fas fa-align-left"></i>
                        <span>Toggle Sidebar</span>
                                           </button>
                    
                </div>
            </nav>

            <h2>Collapsible Sidebar Using Bootstrap 4</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

            <div class="line"></div>

            <h2>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

            <div class="line"></div>

            <h2>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

            <div class="line"></div>

            <h3>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- jQuery CDN - Slim version (=without AJAX) -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- Popper.JS -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#sidebarCollapse').on('click', function () {
                $('#sidebar').toggleClass('active');
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `.currentPage a {}` or add the class directly to the anchor tag